# Projections on eigenspaces of diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be a diagonalizable matrix and let $\mathfrak{A_1}, \dots \mathfrak{A}_n$ the eigenspaces such that

$$\mathbb{C}^{n} = \mathfrak{A_1}\oplus \dots \oplus\mathfrak{A_n}$$

So One can define the projection on each eigenspace by the map $P_i:\mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathfrak{A_i}$ by $Px=x$    if $x \in \mathfrak{A_i}$ and $Px=0$ otherwise.

1)Is this definition correct?

2)Are the projections always mutually orthogonal assuming these hypotheses? I think this immediately follows from the fact that I'm writing the original space as a direct sum.

Comment: add the definition of "mutually orthogonal"

Comment: I'm reading that a projection is orthogonal if and only if it is self-adjoint... Do we need to consider the inner product?

Comment: Presumably you mean $P_i$ rather than $P$. The definition defines a projection (as in $P^2 =P$) but will only be mutually orthogonal if your choices of eigenspace are.

Comment: So if $\mathfrak{A}_i \cap \mathfrak{A}_j =0$ then the respective projections will be mutually orthogonal?

Comment: You need them to be mutually orthogonal.

Comment: Each of the $P_i$ is an orthogonal projection (since $P^* = P$) but that does not automatically mean the $P_i$ are mutually orthogonal unless the choice of eigenspace is orthogonal.

Comment: Maybe the only way to have mutually orthogonal is assuming the matrix is orthgonal diagonalizable? What about this case?

Comment: Yes, that is **iff** $A$ is normal.

Comment: By the way by mutually orthogonal I meant exactly that $P_iP_j=0$ for $i \neq j$. So that is the case of when $A$ is normal?

Comment: As long as you choose the eigenspaces to be mutually orthogonal. If an eigenspace has dimension greater than one you must choose the spanning vectors to be orthogonal.

Comment: Typically the projections are not taken to be orthogonal projections.  Rather, they are defined so that they commute the original operator. Equivalently, they are defined so that the kernel of each projection is spanned by the remaining eigenspaces.

Comment: An important flaw in your definition of $P_i$: it is incorrect to say "$Px = 0$ otherwise". in particular, the kernel $\{x : P_x = 0\}$ must form a subspace of $\Bbb C^n$.